# How to use NN LookupTable in Torch

Tags: lua, neural-network, torch

How do I use nn.LookupTable to convert my vector of vocab indices to a tensor of embedding vectors?
(https://github.com/torch/nn/blob/master/LookupTable.lua)

The network is set up as:

```
self.llstm = LSTM
self.rlstm = LSTM

local modules = nn.Parallel()
  :add(nn.LookupTable(self.vocab_size, self.emb_size))
  :add(nn.Collapse(2))
  :add(self.llstm)
  :add(self.my_module)

self.params, self.grad_params = modules:getParameters
```

In the train step:

```
input = dataset[i]
emb_input = ?
self.llstm.forward(emb_input, reverse)
```

Comment: https://github.com/torch/nn/blob/master/doc/convolution.md#nn.LookupTable

Comment: How to back propagate or update?

Comment: As any `nn` module: `forward(input)` and `backward(input, gradOutput)`